# SmartToken Contract Modifactions

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-debugging, ico

I want to create a Smart Token on the real ethereum-net and I have been test this contract on the ropsten testnet, seems to work perfectly the way I want it, now if I would publish the exact same contract on the real ether net would it work the same way?

And also, am I missing any lethal things or any lethal mistakes that will later on cause an error? any major parts that can be improved and any parts that seem strange?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

/**
 * Math operations with safety checks
 */
contract SafeMath {
function safeMul(uint a, uint b) internal returns (uint) {
    uint c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
}

function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) internal returns (uint) {
    assert(b > 0);
    uint c = a / b;
    assert(a == b * c + a % b);
    return c;
}

function safeSub(uint a, uint b) internal returns (uint) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
}

function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) internal returns (uint) {
    uint c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
}

function max64(uint64 a, uint64 b) internal constant returns (uint64) {
    return a >= b ? a : b;
}

function min64(uint64 a, uint64 b) internal constant returns (uint64) 
{
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

function max256(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns 
(uint256) {
    return a >= b ? a : b;
}

function min256(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns 
(uint256) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

//This is built in the Solidity language anyway as far as I know
function assert(bool assertion) internal {
    if (!assertion) {
        throw;
    }
}
 }

 contract ERC20Basic {
uint public totalSupply;
function balanceOf(address who) constant returns (uint);
function transfer(address to, uint value);
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
 }

  contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
function allowance(address owner, address spender) constant returns 
(uint);

function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value);
function approve(address spender, uint value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint 
value);
 }

 contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic, SafeMath {

mapping(address => uint) balances;

     /**
   * @dev transfer token for a specified address
   * @param _to The address to transfer to.
   * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */

function transfer(address _to, uint _value) {
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], _value);
    balances[_to] = safeAdd(balances[_to], _value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}

      /**
   * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
   * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of. 
   * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
   */
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

 }


 contract StandardToken is BasicToken, ERC20 {

mapping (address => mapping (address => uint)) allowed;

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) {
    var _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

    // Check is not needed because safeSub(_allowance, _value) will already throw if this condition is not met
    // if (_value > _allowance) throw;

    balances[_to] = safeAdd(balances[_to], _value);
    balances[_from] = safeSub(balances[_from], _value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = safeSub(_allowance, _value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
}

function approve(address _spender, uint _value) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
}

function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns 
(uint remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
} 

 }

 contract Ownable {
   address public owner =0x00000;


   /**
    * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the 
 contract to the sender
    * account.
    */
   function Ownable() {
     owner = msg.sender;
   }


   /**
    * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
    */
   modifier onlyOwner() {
     require(msg.sender == owner);
_;
   }


   /**
    * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
    * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
    */
   function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
     require(newOwner != address(0));      
     owner = newOwner;
   }

 }

contract CrowdsaleToken is StandardToken , Ownable {


   uint public startBlock= block.timestamp;
   uint public endBlock= startBlock + noOfSec;



  string public constant name = "EcoToken";
  string public constant symbol = "ECT";
  uint public constant decimals = 0;
  // replace with your fund collection multisig address 
  address public constant multisig = 0x000000; 
  uint public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000;

 function CrowdsaleToken() {
balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  }


  // 1 ether = 400 example tokens 
  uint public constant PRICE = 400;

   function () payable {
     createTokens(msg.sender);
   }

   function createTokens(address recipient) payable {
     if (msg.value == 0) {
       throw;
     }

require(now >= startBlock && now <= endBlock); 

uint tokens = safeDiv(safeMul(msg.value * 1.01 ether, getPrice()), 1000000000000000000 ether);
totalSupply = safeAdd(safeAdd(totalSupply, tokens), INITIAL_SUPPLY);

balances[recipient] = safeAdd(balances[recipient], tokens);

if (!multisig.send(msg.value)) {
  throw;
}
  }

// replace this with any other price function
  function getPrice() constant returns (uint result) {
    return PRICE;
}
  }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't look like a question.

Comment: ... it was a bunch of periods when I made that vote-close vote.

Comment: @taid Please don't edit questions to remove content. Even if a question is closed as too broad, it is still a useful reference and should be preserved. If you have other concerns and feel that the post needs to be deleted, please contact a mod.

Answer (score 2):

First, your contract should work identically on the test-net and the main-net (other than the fact that the state on the two chains is different, of course).

Second--and this is just my opinion--you're making a 'lethal' mistake by  asking to have your smart contract reviewed in a public forum.

If I were 'evil' (I'm not!) I would pretend to be 'helpful' and review your contract. If I found any place where I could steal your money, I would pretend everything was working fine, and then allow you to deploy it and ten seconds after you raised mega-money steal your ether. It's a bad idea to ask for review from anyone other than a known expert on smart contracts.

Comment: omg i wasnt aware of this, what should I do now? Also is there any place where you could steal my money in this contract? also explain to me how he would steal my ether? thank you very much for clarifying this. can i please get in contract with you.

Comment: One should also make sure there is no conflict of interest with that expert reviewing your contract.